# On OpenSuSE (or linux in general) where should a non-service startup script go?

Tags: linux, opensuse, rc

On an OpenSuSE linux machine, I want to run a script when the machine is booted. As the script does not start a service, is /etc/rc.d the correct place for the script?

Thanks.

Comment: Considering that some scripts in /etc/rc.d don't actually leave a process running in the background, meaning that not all of those are "services" per se, I think /etc/rc.d is a good place to leave something you want to be executed at boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's where I've always put them.  There are several scripts in rc.d already which don't actually start a process.  However, you need to write it in a similar fashion to the other startup scripts - have a look at a few to see how they are set up.  Specifically, you should make sure that it's possible to run the script using `/etc/rc.d/myscript start`.